# Find $y''$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus

Find $y''$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

$$xy=x+y$$

I have calculated $y'$ as

$$\frac{y-1}{1-x}=y'$$

which is correct according to the solutions manual but when I try to calculate $y''$ I get

$$y''= \frac{y'(1-x)+y-1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$y''= \frac{y'+y-1}{1-x}$$

but the solutions manual get $y''= \frac{2y'}{1-x}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has been edited a couple of times for formatting. The second expression currently noted for $y''$ does not follow from the first - is this what you intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not solve for $y'$ that only makes matters more complicated. Just differentiate twice and solve for $y''$.

$$xy=x+y \implies y+xy'=1+y' \implies y'+y'+xy''=y''$$

Having these equations you can then solve the separatly for the derivatives:

$$y'=\frac{y-1}{1-x}$$
$$y''=\frac{2}{1-x}y'=\frac{2}{1-x}\frac{y-1}{1-x}$$

Comment: Definitely the easiest way to get to $y''$ rather than differentiating the fraction for $y'$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\frac {y'(1-x)+y-1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac {y'}{1-x}+\frac {y-1}{(1-x)^2}=2\frac {y'}{1-x}$$ because of the formula you already have for $y'$. So the two answers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Up to
$$
y''= \frac{y'(1-x)+y-1}{(1-x)^2}
$$
it looks good. However, from there you simplify the fraction by $1-x$ without taking the $y-1$ in the numerator into account. So instead of $y'' = \frac{y' +y-1}{1-x}$ that you have, it should've been
$$
y''= \frac{y'+\frac{y-1}{1-x}}{1-x}
$$
and finally, we use that we already know that $y' = \frac{y-1}{1-x}$ to make the numerator into $2y'$.